# How to access the getter and setter of a parent object in PHP?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

In a symfony2 application referencing and selling paintings, I have two objects :

- All the paintings are instances of **Painting**
- Some of them are for sale, i associate an instance of **Auction** to them

There is a OneToMany relation between the two, mapped by **Painting**

**My problem :**

```
// In Controller.php  
public function homepageListAction()
{

    $paintings = $this->getPaintingRepository()->findPaintingsForHomepage();
    $auctions  = $this->getPaintingRepository()->findAuctionsForHomepage();

    foreach($paintings as $painting) 
    { 
        $painting->setAboutText(substr($painting->getAboutText(), 0, 150) . '...');
        // This works 
    }

    foreach($auctions as $auction)
    {
        $auction->setAboutText(substr($auction->getAboutText(), 0, 150) . '...');
        // Error : using a member property on a non-object
    }

    // Rest of function
```

With some debuging it appears that **$paintings** is an array of objects, while **$auctions** is an array of arrays, containing the data of the auctions and the paintings they are associated to. Therefore I can easily access the data of Paintings associated to Auctions, but I don't see how to manipulate it in a straightforward way before sending it to my template.

**My question :**

- How can I fetch the Auctions from my database as objects instead of arrays?
  or
- How can I allow my Auctions to access the getter/setters of Paintings inside my controller?

**Various informations :**

Database configuration (Doctrine)

```
Painting ORM
oneToMany:
    painting:
        targetEntity: Auction
        mappedBy: Painting


Auction ORM
manyToOne:
    Painting:
        targetEntity: Painting
        inversedBy: auction
        joinColumn:
            name: painting_id
            referencedColumnName: id
            onDelete: SET NULL
```

Entities (extracts)

```
//painting.php

/**
 * @var text $about_text
 */
private $about_text;

/**
 * Set about_text
 *
 * @param text $aboutText
 */
public function setAboutText($aboutText)
{
    $this->about_text = $aboutText;
}

/**
 * Get about_text
 *
 * @return text 
 */
public function getAboutText()
{
    return $this->about_text;
}

//auction.php

/**
 * @var my\bundle\Entity\Painting
 */
private $Painting;

 /**
 * Set Painting
 *
 * @param my\bundle\Entity\Painting $painting
 */
public function setPainting(\my\bundle\Entity\Painting $painting)
{
    $this->Painting = $painting;
}

/**
 * Get Painting
 *
 * @return my\bundle\Entity\Painting
 */
public function getPainting()
{
    return $this->Painting;
}
```

Queries (both in PaintingRepository.php)

```
public function findPaintingsForHomepage()
{

    $queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('m');

    return $queryBuilder->select('m')
            ->from('MyBundle:Painting', 'm INDEX BY m.id')
            ->orderBy('m.updated_at', 'DESC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute()
    ;
}

public function findAuctionsForHomepage()
{
    $sql = 
    <<<EOF

        SELECT p.*, 
            (a.amount) as auction_amount,
        FROM painting p

        LEFT JOIN auction a
            ON p.id = a.painting_id
        WHERE a.state IS NOT NULL
    EOF
    ;    
    $stmt = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: use the query builder to get results in the `findAuctionsForHomepage` function

Comment: @DevZero With the query builder, will I still be able to write my query in SQL?

Comment: you write the query in chunks as displayed in `findPaintingsForHomepage` function

Comment: @DevZero That's my problem, I simplified the query _a lot_ for the purpose of this question but it comes with much more conditions in my code - easier to write in plain SQL. I'll see what I can do with the queryBuilder though as you seem to say it is the condition for returning objects instead of array. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: you can build a `stdClass` object on the fly with the results also

Comment: I had tried before asking but got a definition error : Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::setAboutText()

Comment: stdClass doesn't have a function called setAboutText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map your plain query results to doctrine entity objects. Read about [native queries](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html).

```
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $rsm = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMappingBuilder($em);
    $rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('my\bundle\Entity\Painting', 'p');
```